# How can I stop image orietation after or before compression in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a classfied website i am working on. I discovered that image taken from mobile phones were not showing up in it acutal orientation view, especially those in protrait. and this happens after the compression.

Please can someone help me to allow images compress in it original orientation as it is in users phone when take.

this is the code I have been using so far

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg","png","gif");
$max_file_size = 1024\*300; //300 kb
$path = "../uploadFiles/"; // Upload directory

// Compress the image files
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {
$info = getimagesize($source_url);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
    
    // save file
    imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);

}


 if ($_FILES['upload']['error'][$f] != 0) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }
        if ($_FILES['upload']['error'][$f] == 0) {
           

if( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $maimmsgs = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                //All smaller files to be compressed.
$emptyd = basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"][$f]);
if($emptyd == ""){
    //echo "empty"."<br>";
}               
else{   
   if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"][$f])) {
       $file_name = "photo".rand(1000,1000000).basename($name);
                    compress_image($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$file_name, 50);
    
                    $count ++; // Number of successfully uploaded files
}}
```

I have been using that and is really working for me. How can i modiefied the code to be able to keep the photo orientation. If possible i saw the below code online, who knows how i can use it with my code above

```
function resample($jpgFile, $thumbFile, $width, $orientation) {
// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($jpgFile);
$height = (int) (($width / $width_orig) \* $height_orig);
// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image   = imagecreatefromjpeg($jpgFile);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
// Fix Orientation
switch($orientation) {
case 3:
$image_p = imagerotate($image_p, 180, 0);
break;
case 6:
$image_p = imagerotate($image_p, 90, 0);
break;
case 8:
$image_p = imagerotate($image_p, -90, 0);
break;
}
// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, $thumbFile, 90);
}
```

Even without that, any solution that works is fine

Comment: Hint: rotate the image before you resize it.

Comment: You want to read the information about the (probably) correct orientation of the image from the images meta data. How you can get that depends on the image format.

Comment: @Ken Lee, Its a public platform. user upload without my consents, so it is not possible for them to be aware of the hint

Comment: @arkascha  can you explicitly explain how to read the orientation and apply to the code

Comment: What I mean is a hint for your **coding** : (1) auto rotate the image , then (2) resize it

Comment: You are aware that image files usually contain meta data? And you are aware that many libraries offer means to read that meta data? Then what keeps you from doing that?